# Show/hide divs based on dropdown selection - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i am tryign to make a timeline, where if you select an item from a dropdown selection box it will display only the information from that selection (era). I found this [Code](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-show-hide-div-using-select-box) which lets me do just that, but once i added a few thigns of my own, it stopped working. i was wondering why this is happening, and what could be done to fix it. 
Full Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select").change(function(){
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
            $(".box").not(".red").hide();
            $(".red").show();
        }
        else if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
            $(".box").not(".green").hide();
            $(".green").show();
        }
        else if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
            $(".box").not(".blue").hide();
            $(".blue").show();
        else if($(this).attr("value")=="maroon"){
            $(".box").not(".maroon").hide();
            $(".maroon").show();
        else if($(this).attr("value")=="magenta"){
            $(".box").not(".magenta").hide();
            $(".magenta").show();
        }
        else{
            $(".box").hide();
        }
    });
}).change();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <select>
        <option>Choose Color</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="maroon">maroon</option>
        <option value="magenta">magenta</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="red box">
</div>
<div class="green box">hello</div>
<div class="blue box">talofa</div>
<div class="maroon box"> <h2>BURGANDY!</h2></div>
<div class="magenta box"> <h2>PINK!</h2></div>
```

EDIT:
I am extremely new to JS and JQuery (Like, Never used either of them before), so explanations are appreciated!

Comment: You're missing some closing brackets near the else's

Comment: OMFG. i feel retarded. Thanks dude! it's bee a long day trying to learn JS xD Thanks so much

Comment: It happens to everyone, GL!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several `syntax` errors . You are not closing the `else if` with `}`. You may want to check `console` for those.

Also, not sure why you are doing `$(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){...` since there can be only one option selected at any given time.

Here is the working code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    var color = $(this).val();
    if (color == "red") {
      $(".box").not(".red").hide();
      $(".red").show();
    } else if (color == "green") {
      $(".box").not(".green").hide();
      $(".green").show();
    } else if (color == "blue") {
      $(".box").not(".blue").hide();
      $(".blue").show();
    } else if (color == "maroon") {
      $(".box").not(".maroon").hide();
      $(".maroon").show();
    } else if (color == "magenta") {
      $(".box").not(".magenta").hide();
      $(".magenta").show();
    } else {
      $(".box").hide();
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select>
    <option>Choose Color</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="maroon">maroon</option>
    <option value="magenta">magenta</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="red box">
</div>
<div class="green box">hello</div>
<div class="blue box">talofa</div>
<div class="maroon box">
  <h2>BURGANDY!</h2>
</div>
<div class="magenta box">
  <h2>PINK!</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Im doing the $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){.. because thats what was in the original from the internet, and i don't know enough about it to realise that it's not needed xD! Thanks though !

Answer (score 2):

You're missing some closing brackets near the else's.
Find a good javascript IDE, something like [sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/), also make sure you read the console messages.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select").change(function(){
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
            $(".box").not(".red").hide();
            $(".red").show();
        }else if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
            $(".box").not(".green").hide();
            $(".green").show();
        }else if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
            $(".box").not(".blue").hide();
            $(".blue").show();
        }else if($(this).attr("value")=="maroon"){
            $(".box").not(".maroon").hide();
            $(".maroon").show();
        }else if($(this).attr("value")=="magenta"){
            $(".box").not(".magenta").hide();
            $(".magenta").show();
        }else{
            $(".box").hide();
        }
    });
}).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <select>
        <option>Choose Color</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="maroon">maroon</option>
        <option value="magenta">magenta</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="red box">Redish!</div>
<div class="green box">hello</div>
<div class="blue box">talofa</div>
<div class="maroon box"> <h2>BURGANDY!</h2></div>
<div class="magenta box"> <h2>PINK!</h2></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers explained the typo.

Here is a simpler version

Fixed the code and added initial hide all css

```js
$(function() {
  $("select").on("change", function() {
    const val = this.value
    $(".box").not("." + val).hide();
    $("." + val).show();
  }).change();
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.maroon {
  background-color: maroon;
}

.magenta {
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select>
    <option>Choose Color</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="maroon">maroon</option>
    <option value="magenta">magenta</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="red box">Red</div>
<div class="green box">Green</div>
<div class="blue box">Blue</div>
<div class="maroon box">
  <h2>Maroon!</h2>
</div>
<div class="magenta box">
  <h2>Magenta!</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Use className or Id instead of direct tag name
  $('.choose-color').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var box = $('.box');

    box.hide(); // hide all boxes

    $('.' + val).show(); // show the current one

  })
});
```

> Ref: http://jsbin.com/zocipil/edit?html,output